# What is the difference between RenderSection and Web Helper

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor

What is the difference between `RenderSection`, `RenderPage` and a Web Helper?

- List item I've used `RenderPage`, and it takes 2 parameters; the name of the file on disk, and an array of `object`s to be passed to that page.
- I've used `RenderSection`, which I believe only takes 1 parameter; the name of the `section`.
- I've also used Web Helpers. This is where I get confused. With Helpers, you can pretty much so everything you can do with `RenderBody`, and `RenderSection`.

Here's where I get confused:

Sections file:

```
@section footer {
   <p>Copyright 2012 blah. Most rights reserved.</p>
}
```

Helper file:

```
@helper header {
   <p>Copyright 2012 blah. Most rights reserved.</p>
}
```

CSHTML File:

```
...
<body>
   @MyHelpers.header()
   @RenderBody()
   @RenderSection("footer", required: true)
</body>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

`RenderSection()` and `RenderBody()` allow you to communicate between the layout page and the content page.
You call these methods in the layout page, and they return content from the content page.

By contrast, helpers can only be called in the file they're defined in.  (or, for global helpers, from anywhere)